# Didn't find class "com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl"

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap

I am trying to consume SAP By-Design SOAP Web service in the Android application, generated web Client through net bean using downloaded WSDL file and added proxy class as a module in the form of the jar file in the android project. when tried to run the application it crashes by popping the error message

```
 javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl"
```

This SOAP Webservice has basic authentication with username and password. and the code is given below

```
public class TriggerWebService {


private Map<String, Object> context;
private ManageCustomerIn port;
CustomerService service;

public  TriggerWebService() {
    Log.i("Constructor","Started+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
//ADDING URL AND CREDENTIALS FOR CONNECT WEBSERVICES


    service = new CustomerService();
    port = service.getBinding();
    Log.i("ramkumar", "++++++++++++++++++++" + port.toString());
    context = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();
    context.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "https://my316508.sapbydesign.com/sap/bc/srt/scs/sap/managecustomerin1");
    context.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "_ANDROIDPOC");
    context.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "Welcome1");
    try {
        SSLContext sSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = null;
        sSLContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sSLContext.getSocketFactory());

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException ex) {
    }


}

public CustomerBundleMaintainConfirmationMessageSyncV1 maintainBundleV1(CustomerBundleMaintainRequestMessageSyncV1 customerBundleMaintainRequestSyncV1) throws StandardFaultMessage {
    Log.i("ram", "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$" + customerBundleMaintainRequestSyncV1.toString());
    return port.maintainBundleV1(customerBundleMaintainRequestSyncV1);
}
}
```

Comment: Android do not support Sun API. Is this Android code?

Comment: yes, this is android code, what is the best way to consume SOAP web Service if this not support ?

Comment: I have no idea, because I often use REST instead of SOAP. After a bit searching, you may check this http://simpligility.github.io/ksoap2-android/index.html